# printf interpretation of newline characters with parameter expansion string replacement

Tags: string, bash, shell, parameter-expansion

I have a string: `string="foo=bar boo=far rab=oof raf=oob"`

I want to replace all white-space within the string with a newline character: `string=${string// /$"\n"}`

When I use `printf`, bash prints:

```sh
~$ printf "%s" "$string"
foo=bar\nboo=far\nrab=oof\nraf=oob
```

However, when I mistyped the command as `printf %s""$string`, I got:

```sh
~$ printf %s""$string
foo=bar
boo=far
rab=oof
raf=oob
```

What is the difference in `printf "%s" "$string"` and `printf %s""$string` that `printf` will only interpret newline characters in one of the commands?

Comment: Use `$'\n'` not `$"\n"` e.g.`string=${string// /$'\n'}`

Comment: Just `printf ${string// /'\n'}` works

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$"\n"` looks for a translation of `\n` in the current locale, but as it doesn't find anything, it just returns `\n` (see [How to add localization support to your bash scripts (BashFAQ/098)](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/098) for details).

1. `printf %s "$string"` (quotes around %s aren't needed) takes the contents of the $string and prints it as is.
2. `printf %s""$string` concatenates %s with an empty string and the contents of the variable. `\n` thus gets into the template and is interpreted as a newline.

You can use `set -xv` to make the shell show you how it interprets the commands and variables.

Creating a printf template from unsecured strings is dangerous.
I'd recommend a different way:

```
s=${string// /$'\n'}
printf %s "$s"
```

The `$'\n'` expands into a real newline character, so $s will contain actual newlines. You can then print it directly.

Another way would be

```
printf '%s\n' $string
```

without changing the value of $string. Non-quoted string gets word split, and each resulting word is printed using the template which adds a newline to it.

Comment: Thanks! Still getting confused with single and double quotes in bash